# How to Increase Youtube Quota and How much i will get per day

Tags: youtube-api

we tried of using Youtube upload api, but per day only i can able to upload max of 5video(without edit, only upload), can you tell me how to increase the Youtube Quota and how much they will increase per day. Thanks you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: Thank you for your response.
These are our concerns listed below; if you can help us solve those, it will be great.

1. What is the maximum limit we can achieve in quota?
2. Video Copyright issue while uploading using API

Comment: I can only help you concerning 1.: [as far as I experienced](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/11#issuecomment-1325539722) it seems that you can request any amount of quota but you are not guaranteed to be granted that amount.